# mule - mapping array or object JSON response

Tags: java, json, mapping, mule

I call a web service that returns a json array in case of success:

```
[
  {"name":"a"},
  {"name":"b"}
]
```

And in case of failure, it returns an object:

```
{
 "status":"Failed",
 "describtion":"Error occured"
}
```

How to map both response in order to handle them?

Answer (score 1):

You can use different transformation based on the web service response code.

Something like this:

```
<choice> 
  <when expression="#[message.inboundProperties['http.status'] == 200]">
    <!-- transform success response -->
  </when>
  <otherwise>
    <!-- transform failure response -->
  </otherwise>
</choice>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(yourdata);
String statistics = json.getString("status");

if(status == null){
// Show error message
}else{
  String statistics = json.getString("name");
 }

 Try this. Let me know if it not work. I'll give another solution
```

Comment: No, it's not working. it gives th following exception: org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 of [

Answer (score 0):

Use below Transform Message after HTTP you will get proper output..

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
    Status:"Success" when payload.status != 'Failed' otherwise "Failure",
    Describtion:payload.describtion when payload.status == 'Failed' otherwise null,
    Data:payload when payload.status != 'Failed' otherwise null
}
```

After this your Output will be

1.Success case

```
{
    "Status": "Success",
    "Describtion": null,
    "Data": [
        {
            "name": "a"
        },
        {
            "name": "b"
        }
    ]
}
```

2.Failure Case

```
{
    "Status": "Failure",
    "Describtion": "Error occured",
    "Data": null
}
```